# Permission denied for mmap /dev/mem, even with CAP_SYS_RAWIO, but works as root

Tags: io, mmap, memory-mapping, linux-capabilities

we have an x86 mainboard, which has some GPIOs that are accessible using MMIO (memory-mapped input/output). The I/O region is located at address `0xfd6d0680` and following (only one page).

The program works fine when executed as root (with sudo). But the call to mmap() fails when executing it as a normal user. This is expected in the normal case, but as far as I understand, it should work when the executable is given the CAP_SYS_RAWIO capability:

```
$ ./ipc_gpio out=0
Read board name: 'MX370QD'
ERROR: open '/dev/mem' failed: Permission denied (13)
$ sudo setcap CAP_SYS_RAWIO+ep ipc_gpio
$ ./ipc_gpio out=0
Read board name: 'MX370QD'
ERROR: open '/dev/mem' failed: Permission denied (13)
$ sudo ./ipc_gpio out=0
Read board name: 'MX370QD'

$ getcap ipc_gpio
ipc_gpio = cap_sys_rawio+ep
```

Are there other restrictions in place for this address region? Or is another capability required for this purpose?
I suppose that making the executable setuid root (or maybe setgid kmem) would work, but from a security point of view, I'd rather avoid going that far.

Thank you!

Best regards, Philipp

Comment: What does `ls -l /dev/mem` say?

Comment: `crw-r----- 1 root kmem 1, 1 Nov 12 14:22 /dev/mem` Nothing offending, as far as I can tell...

Comment: What user/group are you running your program as?

Comment: As the first unprivileged user (1000:1000) would be the plan. The temporary fix is to run it as setuid root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CAP_SYS_RAWIO` isn't all you need to access `/dev/mem`. Its regular file permissions apply too. You either need `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` (if you just want to read and not write), `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE`, setgid `kmem`, or change the permissions or set file ACLs on `/dev/mem`.

Comment: Thanks, CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE fixed it. I must have forgotten that everything is just a file...

Comment: @PhilippBurch Note that from a security point of view, your binary now has enough permissions to trivially escalate itself to do anything it could if it were just setuid root.